# replace multiple elements with .splice() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to Javascript and i am doing a course on it atm. I am searching for a way to replace multiple items in an array with 1 item but i only know how to replace a single one.here is my snipped:

```js
let secretMessage = ["Learning", "isn't", "about", "what", "you", "get", "easily", "the", "first", "time,", "it's", "about", "what", "you", "can", "figure", "out.", "-2015,", "Chris", "Pine,", "Learn", "JavaScript"];

secretMessage.pop();
secretMessage.push('to','program');
secretMessage[6] = 'right';
secretMessage.shift();
secretMessage.unshift('Programming');
```

and this is what i am supposed to do: 
Use an array method to remove the strings get, right, the, first, time,, and replace them with the single string know,.

Answer (score 4):

The `.splice()` method lets you replace multiple elements in an array with one, two, or however many elements you like. Just use the syntax:

`.splice(startingIndex, numDeletions, replacement1, replacement2, ... )`

where:

- `startingIndex` is the index of the array that contains the first element you want to remove
- `numDeletions` is the number of *consecutive* items in the array you want to remove
- `replacement1`, `replacement2`, `...` (however many) are the elements you wish to add to the array, beginning at `startingIndex`

In your case:

- `get` is at index `5`
- `get`, `easily`, `the`, `first`, `time` is `5` Strings consecutively
- only want one replacement: the String `know`

So you would say `.splice(5, 5, "know")`

Can also refer to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Cheers!

Comment: If you want to replace multiple items that are not consecutive, then you can alternatively use `secretMessage[5] = "know"`, `secretMessage[2] = "tomato"`, etc. I think using `.splice()` to replace a single item such as `secretMessage.splice(5, 1, "know")` is a little too verbose.